# Why did the scientific community stop using hydrogen as the main measure for the atomic mass unit?

Tags: mass, atomic-physics, units, history, metrology

The only thing I could find is that the community switched form one hydrogen atom to 1/16 of Oxygen-16 (which they thought to be the only isotope that exists at time because they had no concept of isotopes yet) even though they were approximately the same value was because oxygen "was more amenable to experimental determination" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)).

That's from Wikipedia, so I am still skeptical. If that is the case, what about oxygen allowed it to be more amenable to experimental determination?

Comment: H-1 was the standard for a century, we used O-16 from 1903 to 1961, when we switched to C-12.

Comment: This question is certainly on-topic here, but I think it's more about chemistry than atomic physics, and the chemists may be able to give us more details on why O was easier to deal with than H. OTOH, atomic physics *is* relevant, for two reasons: isotopes, and the fact that you can't determine atomic mass just by counting protons & neutrons.

Comment: You should consider posting your question here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually, physicists used Oxygen -16 =16.00000000;  chemists used oxygen (naturally occurring isotope mix) - 16.00000000.  Much hilarity ensued.